# cannot export a COM class using __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, com, static-libraries, atl

I am trying to generate a static library and I have a wrapper around a COM object provided by a hardware manufacturer. I have never used COM ever but I read that Visual Studio will not create the library if no symbols are exported.

My class has the following signature:

```
class DeviceWrapper: public IDeviceCallback
```

The `IDeviceCallback` is defined as:

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("DD04E5EC-7415-42AB-AE4A-E80C4DFC044A")
IDeviceCallback : public IUnknown
```

I must confess I do not know what this signature means.

So, I tried to export it by:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) DeviceWrapper: public IDeviceCallback
```

And I get the following errors:

```
error C2039: '=' : is not a member of 'IDeviceCallback'
error C2664: 'DeviceWrapper &DeviceWrapper::operator =(const DeviceWrapper &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const IDeviceCallback' to 'const DeviceWrapper &'
```

Not sure what I can do to create this static library. Any pointers (no pun intended) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I am trying to generate a static library..."* - You don't export symbols in static libraries. A static lib is just a collection of objs ganged together to consumption by whatever links against it, as if it were linking against the  contained stack of objs. It sounds to me like you don't need this DeviceWrapper class *at all*. Rather, you just need a function in your static lib that creates the com object from your 3rd party in the usual manners (such as CoCreateInstance) and returns a `IDeviceCallback` pointer .

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your comment. you are right, of course. I was confused by why VS does not create the .lib file. It only does so when I overload the = operator and the copy constructor...Well, I defined them and deleted them but then it generates the lib file....